# While I working on a project in ReactJs I am stuck in a portion does anyone know how to fix this? the error image is also given in the code downbelow

Tags: html, reactjs

```
    return (
  <Nav>
    <Logo>
      <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney+" />
    </Logo>

    {!userName ? (
      <Login onClick={handleAuth}>Login</Login>
    ) : (
      <>
        <NavMenu>
          <a href="/home">
            <img src="Assests/images/home-icon.svg" alt="HOME" />
            <span>HOME</span>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="Assests/images/search-icon.svg" alt="SEARCH" />
            <span>SEARCH</span>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="Assests/images/watchlist-icon.svg" alt="WATCHLIST" />
            <span>WATCHLIST</span>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="Assests/images/original-icon.svg" alt="ORIGINALS" />
            <span>ORIGINALS</span>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="Assests/images/movie-icon.svg" alt="MOVIES" />
            <span>MOVIES</span>
          </a>
          <a>
            <img src="Assests/images/series-icon.svg" alt="SERIES" />
            <span>SERIES</span>
          </a>
        </NavMenu>
        <SignOut>
          <UserImg src={userPhoto} alt={userName} />
          <DropDown>
            <span onClick={handleAuth}>Sign out</span>
          </DropDown>
        </SignOut>
      </>
    )}
  </Nav>
);
```

[error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxqXu.png)

*this is the error I get right now if I make that tag a name it will fully disorder my code.Please help me.*
I was trying to make a clone of a website to study. I fully crosschecked with the resources I got. They are getting the right way, but for me its not working.

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: what is your version of react?

Comment: The version is important here. You may have to use <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> instead of the syntax sugar <></>

Comment: <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> worked. Thz for the help